# BottomSheet not hiding fully when swipe down. Partially Hidden

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I have a BottomSheet on my App but the problem is when I swipe it down instead of hiding it fully it stays partially. Here is the picture

[image]

My goal here is to hide it fully when swiping down

Here is my code

```
open class RoundedBottomSheetFull : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {


    override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme)
        dialog.setOnShowListener {

            val bottomSheetDialog = it as BottomSheetDialog
            val parentLayout =
                    bottomSheetDialog.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
            parentLayout?.let { it ->
                val behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(it)
                setupFullHeight(it)
                behaviour.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            }

            dialog.behavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
                override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                    if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }

                override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
                    if (BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED == 1) {
                        dismiss()
                        BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN
                    }
                }
            })
        }


        return dialog
    }

}


private fun setupFullHeight(bottomSheet: View) {
    val layoutParams = bottomSheet.layoutParams
    layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    bottomSheet.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

and here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btnBarManagement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:elevation="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgBack"
                android:backgroundTint="#f39c12"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_edittext"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>


            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/man_bold"
                    android:text="Comments about Bar Name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCommentCount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/man_reg"
                    android:text="Total Comment(s) : 0"
                    android:textSize="11dp"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            tools:listitem="@layout/layout_list_comments"
            android:id="@+id/rvComments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.50sp"
        android:background="#757575" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:paddingTop="15sp"
                android:paddingBottom="15sp"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:id="@+id/etComment"
                android:backgroundTint="#F0F0F0"
                android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="13sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/man_reg"
                android:paddingStart="10sp"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:paddingEnd="10sp"
                android:hint="Type here to start commenting..."
                android:text=""
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_edittext"></EditText>

            <LinearLayout
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:alpha="0.5"
                    android:id="@+id/lnSumbmit"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"></ImageView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

In case you need more just tell me. This is the only code I think needed. My target is to hide the bottomsheet when swipping down

Comment: what happens if you set `app:behavior_hideable="true"`?

Answer (score 1):

Add this property in XML

```xml
app:behavior_skipCollapsed="true"
```

When the `BottomSheet` is in `EXPANDED` state and you swipe down, it initially enters `COLLAPSED` state where it is partially visible. The flag `behavior_skipCollapsed` allows it to skip this `COLLAPSED` state and directly enter `HIDDEN` state where it is completely hidden.

Answer (score 1):

```java
 val behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from<LinearLayout>(binding.root)
  behavior.addBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetCallback)
private val mBottomSheetCallback: BottomSheetCallback = object : BottomSheetCallback() {
        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                dismiss();
            }
        }

        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
            // ignores
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

use `skipCollapsed` in order to avoid `BottomSheetDialogFragment` to have the collapsed state

```
behaviour.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
// Add this
behaviour.skipCollapsed = true
```

Also, you dont need `addBottomSheetCallback` any more because the dialog will dismess it self when the user slide the dialog down.

Answer (score 0):

you can set:

```
app:behavior_hideable="true"
```

or

```
bottomSheetBehavior.isHideable = true
```

and then, set:

```
bottomSheetBehavior.skipCollapsed = true
```